# Excel use Checkbox in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I need to verify if an activex checkbox is checked in my vba code, however, when I try - "  If Checkbox1.Value = True Then"  it is asking for variable not defined.  What am i missing?

Comment: Is your checkbox named `CheckBox1`? How about `Sheet1.CheckBox`? Is it an activeX checkbox, or a form control checkbox?

Comment: ActiveX control and I tried sheet("BalanceSheet").checkbox1.  Still having issue.  It also is the activesheet.

Comment: And you are certain it's named Checkbox1? Other than that, I don't see anything wrong with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
Sub dural()
    If ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CheckBox1").Object.Value = True Then
        MsgBox "it is checked"
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Note this is for a "standalone" ActiveX checkbox *(not on a userform)*

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
If Me.Checkbox1 = True Then
  'whatever code goes here
End If
```

Comment: this is Excel not access vba - I believe I need to pass the sheet name...

Comment: `Me` is fine to use in Excel VBA, however, it's superfluous in this instance. If this code is in the worksheet's vba code, then it will work. If the code is in a module, then `me` would be referencing the module.

Comment: Did you look at this forum at all? - http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/45786-if-clause-visual-basic-applications-look-checkbox-if-its-checked-not.html